# Accessing request payload from RESTful calls in Tornado Web

Tags: rest, backbone.js, tornado

I have a basic app set up using Backbone.js and Tornado Web. When I save my Backbone model, it fires off a POST request to one of my handlers' post methods. I want to access the variables inside the payload but the arguments dictionary is empty.

```
Request Payload
{"text":"dghjdg","date":"2012-02-05T11:23:46.105Z","author":"Kevin"}
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: TornadoServer/2.2
```

It seems as if `self.get_argument` in the handler only collects data from `Form Data` in the request header and not the `Request Payload` part. How can I access any of the variables in the Request Payload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request body (or payload) can be accessed using [self.request.body](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest). Obviously you must decode the JSON format, e.g. `json.loads(self.request.body)`.